# Program stops when running @click.command

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I am using `@click.command` to do some things with my code. However, before that, I tried the code:

```
import click
import random

@click.command()
@click.option('--total', default=3, help='Number of vegetables to output.')
def veg(total):
    """ Basic method will return a random vegetable"""
    for number in range(total):
        print(random.choice(['Carrot', 'Potato', 'Turnip', 'Parsnip']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    veg()
    print('End function')
```

I do not understand why the program stops immediately when done with the `veg()` function. What do I have to do to keep the program running and run `print('End function')`?

Comment: So you're saying "Carrot" etc. *does* print, but "End function" *does not* print?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my expression

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because the default behavior is to invoke the script in standalone mode. Click will then handle exceptions and convert them into error messages and the function will never return but shut down the interpreter. - [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/).

Set `standalone_mode` to False to change it:

```
import click
import random

@click.command()
@click.option('--total', default=3, help='Number of vegetables to output.')
def veg(total):
    """ Basic method will return a random vegetable"""
    for number in range(total):
        print(random.choice(['Carrot', 'Potato', 'Turnip', 'Parsnip']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    veg.main(standalone_mode=False)
    print('End function')

Turnip
Carrot
Carrot
End function
```