# Is there a way to hand the command line parsing to python-click but then have click hand execution back over to my code?

Tags: python, python-click

When I run the code below, nothing below the domains() call is processed. The gibberish doesn't even throw an exception. It seems like to use click you have to do *everything* the click way, which as best I can tell is to move all of my code into the decorator functions?

**Is there a way to hand the command line parsing to click but then have click hand execution back over to my code?**

```
import click
my_cfg = { 'domains': [], 'def_domains': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com'] } 

@click.command()
@click.option('--domain', '-d', multiple=True, type=str, nargs=1, default=my_cfg['def_domains'])
def domains(domain):
    click.echo('\n'.join(domain))
    my_cfg['domains'].append(domain)
domains()

fgddtruhygtuit5r # No exception thrown!! Once domains() is called my code never runs

### Bunch of code here that I cannot easily move into domains() ###
```

Running python 3.10.x on Windows from within PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version is pass in standalone_mode=False when calling your click commands.

Found the answer in [Program stops when running @click.command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55757926/program-stops-when-running-click-command). And I learned about it in [Using the Python 'click' library's parser as a simple function](https://www.trueblade.com/blogs/news/extending-the-python-click-library-to-allow-using-commands-as-functions).

Here's an example:

```
import click
my_cfg = {
    'domains':     [],
    'def_domains': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com'],
    }

@click.command()
@click.option('--domain', '-d', multiple=True, type=str, nargs=1, default=my_cfg['def_domains'])
def domains(domain):
    my_cfg['domains'].append(domain)

domains(standalone_mode=False)

print(f"my_cfg: {my_cfg}")
```

for_testing.py

```
my_cfg: {'domains': [('stackoverflow.com', 'google.com')], 'def_domains': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']}
```

for_testing.py -d duckduckgo.com

```
my_cfg: {'domains': [('duckduckgo.com',)], 'def_domains': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']}
```

for_testing.py -d duckduckgo.com -d google.com -d bing.com

```
my_cfg: {'domains': [('duckduckgo.com', 'google.com', 'bing.com')], 'def_domains': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com']}
```

Edit:  You'll need to handle exceptions and even exiting for --version, -h, and -help yourself.  Here's some code I kludged together:

```
def process_cli_using_click(my_cli):
    #param my_cli: The function you defined via click to process the command line arguments
    click_invoke_rc = None

    try:
        click_invoke_rc = my_cli(standalone_mode=False)
    except click.exceptions.NoSuchOption as err:
        print(f"{err}")
        print(f"Try running the program with -h or --help.")
        exit(3)
    except click.exceptions.UsageError as err:
        print(f"{err}")
        print(f"Try running the program with -h or --help.")
        exit(5)
    except:
        err = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print(f"An unexpected command line processing error occurred:")
        print(f"{err}")
        print(f"Try running the program with -h or --help.")
        exit(10)

    if click_invoke_rc == 0:  # Catch if -h, --help, --version, or something unknown was specified
        exit(1)
```